# Prevent New Line Formation in json_normalize Data Frames

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, csv

I am working to flatten some tweets into a wide data frame. I simply use the pandas.json_normalize function on my to perform this.

I then save this data frame into a CSV file. The CSV format when uploaded produces some rows that are associated with the above, rather than holding all the data on a single row. I discovered this issue when uploading the CSV into R and into Domo.

When I run the following command in a jupyter notebook the CSV loads fine,

`sb_2019 = pd.read_csv('flat_tweets.csv',lineterminator='\n',low_memory=False)`

Without the `lineterminator` I see this error:

```
 Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file.
```

**Needs:**

I am looking for a post-processing step to eliminate the need for a the `lineterminator`. I need to open the CSV in platforms and languages that do not have this specification. How might I go about doing this?

**Note:**
I am working with over 700k tweets. The json_normalize function works great on small pieces of my data where issues are being found. When I run json_normalize on the whole dataset I am finding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **'\r\n'** or **'\r'** as lineterminator, and not '\n'.

This solution would be helpful too, opening in universal-new-line mode:

```
sb_2019 = pd.read_csv(open('flat_tweets.csv','rU'), encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
```

Comment: I can open the data in python fine. The issue relates to opening the data in other languages and platforms without the ability to specify the `lineterminator`.